# Azure blob authorization header

Tags: ios, rest, azure, azure-blob-storage, refit

I am trying to use [refit](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit) to upload to azure blob storage from a Xamarin iOS application. This is the interface configuration I am using for Refit:

```
[Headers("x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob")]
[Put("/{fileName}")]
Task<bool> UploadAsync([Body]byte[] content, string sasTokenKey,
[Header("Content-Type")] string contentType);
```

Where the sasTokenKey parameter looks like this:

```
"/content-default/1635839001660743375-66f93195-e923-4c8b-a3f1-5f3f9ba9dd32.jpeg?sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=Up26vDxQikFqo%2FDQjRB08YtmK418rZfKx1IHbYKAjIE%3D&se=2015-11-23T18:59:26Z&sp=w"
```

This is how I am using Refit to call the azure blob server:

```
var myRefitApi = RestService.For<IMyRefitAPI>("https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net");
myRefitApi.UploadAsync(photoBytes, sasTokenKey, "image/jpeg"
```

However I am getting the follow error:

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Server failed to 
authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is 
formed correctly including the signature.)
```

The SAS url is working fine if I call it directly like this

```
var content = new StreamContent(stream);
            content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "jpeg");
            content.Headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
var task = HttpClient.PutAsync(new Uri(sasTokenUrl), content);
task.Wait();
```

So basically I am just trying to do the same thing using Refit.
Any idea how to get Refit working with Azure Blob Storage?

Thanks!

[UPDATE] I am now able to upload the bytes to the azure blob server but something seems to be wrong with the byte data because I am not able to view the image. Here is the code I am using to convert to byte array.

```
byte[] bytes;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   stream.Position = 0;
   stream.CopyTo(ms);
   ms.Position = 0;
   bytes = ms.ToArray();
}
```

[UPDATE] Got it fixed by using stream instead of byte array!

Comment: I don't see how you're using the SAS token in the refit code. Could you include that portion or add some comments to clarify?

Comment: Hi @Emily please see the clarified question above!

Comment: I don't know anything about refit in the slightest, but have you tried sending the sas token not encoded? I see %2F and %3D and I'm curious if refit is encoding those a second time.

Comment: I am now able to blob the bytes :) but I am not able to view the image so it seems there is something wrong with the bytes I am blobbing. I added the code which shows I am converting from stream to bytes array. See the updated question.

Comment: Posted my comment as an answer since it looks like I guessed right. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see %2F and %3D and I'm curious if refit is encoding those a second time. Try sending the token without encoding it.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect use of `Authorization` header. You use `Authorization` header when you want to authorize the requests using account key. If you have the `Shared Access Signature` then you really don't need this header as the authorization information is included in the SAS itself. You can simply use the SAS URL for uploading files.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I updated my question and changed the interface configuration to use the SAS url. However I am still getting error about the authorization. I would prefer to use Refit since I am using it for all my other REST endpoints. I think I am just setting the wrong configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not aware of Refit that you're using. Would you mind sharing a link about that so that I can read up more about it. However looking at the error, I think there's something wrong with your SAS token itself. Please check for the following things: 1) SAS has not expired 2) SAS has `write` permissions. Also please share the code for getting the SAS token itself.

Comment: I made some updates. Please see the link to Refit documentation at top. The SAS token is working fine if I call it directly... see code updates at the bottom.